# fastapi docs , Pydantic BaseModel, request example missing

Tags: fastapi, documentation, pydantic

```
from pydantic.v1 import *

self._router.add_api_route(
    "/v1/embeddings",
    self.create_embedding,
    methods=["POST"],
    dependencies=(
        [Security(self._auth_service, scopes=["models:read"])]
        if self.is_authenticated()
        else None
    ),
)

async def create_embedding(self, request: Request) -> Response:
    body = CreateEmbeddingRequest.parse_obj(await request.json())
    model_uid = body.model

    try:
        model = await (await self._get_supervisor_ref()).get_model(model_uid)
    except ValueError as ve:
        logger.error(str(ve), exc_info=True)
        await self._report_error_event(model_uid, str(ve))
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(ve))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, exc_info=True)
        await self._report_error_event(model_uid, str(e))
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

    try:
        embedding = await model.create_embedding(body.input)
        return Response(embedding, media_type="application/json")
    except RuntimeError as re:
        logger.error(re, exc_info=True)
        await self._report_error_event(model_uid, str(re))
        self.handle_request_limit_error(re)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(re))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, exc_info=True)
        await self._report_error_event(model_uid, str(e))
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

class CreateEmbeddingRequest(BaseModel):
    model: str
    input: Union[str, List[str], List[int], List[List[int]]] = Field(
        description="The input to embed."
    )
    user: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "input": "The food was delicious and the waiter...",
            }
        }
```

I want to declare the request example in request body like that [scheenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTaky.png).
but the result of my code is like that
[scheenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDITP.png)
Who can help me, thanks in advance.

Operating System

Linux

Operating System Details

CentOS 7

FastAPI Version

0.109.2

Pydantic Version

2.6.4

Python Version

3.10.13

Additional Context

my Pydantic Version is V2，but my code import pydantic.v1

more details in: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/11370